# Client vs Publisher in Azure Event Hubs

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Azure Event Hubs' documentation mentions such terms as `client` and `publisher`. For example, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-authentication-and-security-model-overview#client-authentication)

> The Event Hubs security model is based on a combination of Shared Access Signature (SAS) tokens and event publishers. An event publisher defines a virtual endpoint for an event hub. The publisher can only be used to send messages to an event hub. It is not possible to receive messages from a publisher.
>
> Typically, an event hub employs one publisher per client. All messages that are sent to any of the publishers of an event hub are enqueued within that event hub. Publishers enable fine-grained access control and throttling.

First, I thought that `client` is e.g. some real device, which sends data to the Event Hub, and `publisher` is the entry point in the Event Hub, which knows how to receive events from devices.

However, [following place in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-publishers) adds greater confusion.

> Any entity that sends data to an event hub is an event producer, or event publisher. Event publishers can publish events using HTTPS or AMQP 1.0. Event publishers use a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token to identify themselves to an event hub, and can have a unique identity, or use a common SAS token.

So, what is the difference between them?

Comment: Great question. I read the same article and have the same question. Specifically because my HTTPS Authorization token is returning 40104: Invalid token audience, and apparently this has something to do with the publisher. But I can't see 'publisher' anywhere in the event hubs configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In the quote you provided, my understanding is that "client" is referring to any distinct group of users - maybe one app, or maybe the apps for a certain company if you wanted to group them that way.
A publisher is a construct in code. There is more detail in this document, including how to revoke publishers (which is mentioned but not described in detail in the security doc you linked).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-programming-guide